# Make navbar close on click of menu item

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm having trouble making my navbar disappear when clicking on one of the menu items when I'm in the mobile version of the website. I know there are already questions here with similar problems but most of the solutions are using jquery and I'm really new to javascript so I'm having trouble with that :/ I'd really appreciate some help with this, I'm at my wits' end!

**The problem:** In mobile I have a menu button that opens a full screen navbar with my menu items. Clicking the button works perfectly, it makes the navbar appear and disappear. However, when clicking on one of the links it scrolls to the right position on the page but the navbar stays open. I tried adding an eventListener to the menu items just like for the menu button but that didn't work at all...

**Here's the code:**

HTML

```
<nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"
          ><img
            src="./images/original_white.png"
            alt="disco milk logo"
            width="300px"
            height="auto"
            class="logo-still"
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menunav">
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#about">about us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#say-hello">say hello!</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
          <img
            src="./images/menu_icon.png"
            alt="menu icon"
            class="burger-icon"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    width: 100vw;
    padding-left: 37px;
    padding-right: 37px;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #231f20;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
```

and the JS

```
const navSlide = ()=>{
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    
    burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        // Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        // Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
            if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 5 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });


}

navSlide();
```

I really appreciate any help!! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// insert this after your js variables
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li a").forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        // Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });
});
// I think you get the idea
```

Comment: I have made a navbar that can work without js, if you are interested  knock me

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The code you suggested worked well, it made the navbar close. The only problem was that when I opened it again the menu links had disappeared, so I changed the code a little bit to include the link.style.animation and now everything works great!